# Bypass email sending in c#

Tags: c#, debugging, smtp

I'm debugging an app that sends an email after a button is clicked, but the the email is sent from a component that it uses and I don't have access to its source, it uses the localhost as the smtp server. Is it possible to skip this email sending? I don't want to install an smtp server just to do this...

thanks!

Comment: If you don't have access to the source code - no.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353439/development-smtp-server-for-windows

Comment: You can investigate public API which provided by component you are using

Comment: Can you not comment out the code that runs the stuff for which you don't have source access?

Comment: no I can't because it does some processing, it is acually a vb6 dll... but I solved it using a fake smtp server, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install a lightweight debug SMTP server like [PaperCut](http://papercut.codeplex.com/).

There is virtually no overhead. No real emails get sent, it just allows you to see the content of what would be sent.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to add a setting to the config file to write the email as a file.

```
<specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\test"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure that mentioned component provides such configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to create a wrapper class to abstract the 3rd party object from your library, then when debugging use a dummy wrapper class instead of the live component one. An additional advantage to this method is your dummy could easily be programmed to dump the emails to a file so you could see what the email output would look like as well (or create programmatic tests to test the content of the email for certain operations, without involving an email server).

For instance, you could have a class named Emailer that takes an IEmailProvider instance to use for sending email (IEmailProvider.SendEmail(...)). Then you could have two classes that implement IEmailProvider, one that calls the third party library and is used by default in your application, and one that is your dummy wrapper that does nothing with the content or writes it to disk.
So something like:

```
public class Emailer{
   private IEmailProvider _provider;

   public Emailer(IEmailProvider provider){
      _provider = provider;
   }

   public SendEmail(...){
      _provider.SendEmail();
   }
}

interface IEmailProvider{
   SendEmail(...);
}

public RealEmailProvider : IEmailProvider{
   // ... real code to implement send email method
}

public FakeEmailProvider : IEmailProvider{
   public SendEmail(...){ /* Do Nothing? */ }
}
```

Without knowing how your code is setup, I don't know whether using a Singleton for Email would be your best bet, some sort of manual Dependance Injection, a Dependency Injection framework, or maybe even other methods.

The extra advantage from doing it this way is that if you later want to add extra logic to log every email, communicate in a different way, or replace that email component, all you have to do is update your real EmailProvider instance without touching any of the code that builds and decides to send the email. It also means you don't have any additional 3rd party software to install, reducing the complexity of your development or test environments.