# Intercept e-mails before sending (SmtpClient)

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I'm using the following code to send an e-mail:

```
using (var mailMessage = new MailMessage("from@example.com", "to@example.com"))
{
    mailMessage.Subject = "My topic";
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mailMessage.Body = "My content";
    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to intercept the e-mail, and change the subject as well as the receiver, when I'm using this code in my test environment. I want to be able to configure something like this in my web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
  [...]
  <add key="RedirectAllEmailsTo" value="someone.else@example.com" />
</appSettings>
```

When the value of "RedirectAllEmailsTo" isnt empty, I would like all the e-mails in my application, to be sent to the specified e-mail, instead of the assigned receiver in my **MailMessage** instance.

I would also like to change the topic of the **MailMessage** to indicate who's supposed to receive the e-mail to something like this: "My topic (receiver: to@example.com)".

Is it possible to intercept e-mails, and change the receiver as well as the subject, or do I have to write my own class, instead of using SmtpClient directly?

This is my code. Hopefully there's a better way to handle it.

```
public static void SendEmail(MailMessage mailMessage)
{
    var redirectAllEmailsTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectAllEmailsTo"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectAllEmailsTo) == false)
    {
        mailMessage.Subject += string.Format(" (to: {0}, cc: {1}, bcc: {2})",
            string.Join(", ", mailMessage.To.Select(m => m.Address)),
            string.Join(", ", mailMessage.CC.Select(m => m.Address)),
            string.Join(", ", mailMessage.Bcc.Select(m => m.Address)));

        mailMessage.To.Clear();
        mailMessage.CC.Clear();
        mailMessage.Bcc.Clear();
        mailMessage.To.Add(redirectAllEmailsTo);
    }
    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not have a dev config file that uses a dev smtp server?

Comment: @Oded: You might as well make that an answer :)

Comment: @leppie - fair enough. Done.

Answer (score 2):

may be you shoule just create a simple wrapper class for `SmtpClient` with `BeforeSend` event and/or the desired topic operations, like this?

```
class SmtpClientWrapper
{
    SmtpClient _client = new SmtpClient();

    public event EventHandler BeforeSend;

    private void PreprocessMesage(MailMessage message)
    {
        //do something with the message topic, as you desire
    }

    public void Send(MailMessage message)
    {
        BeforeSend(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        PreprocessMessage(message);
        _client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of dealing with this issue (that is, not sending email in a development environment) is **not** to intercept emails.

It is to have a separate `*.config` file for your development environment than the one you have in production - this can be managed using [config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) (with or without [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)), or whatever home brewed solution.

This config file would point at a development SMTP server - one that only takes the messages and doesn't send them on. There are [plenty of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353439/development-smtp-server-for-windows) of doing this.

Comment: Very interesting. In this specific case, I want all e-mails sent, to a specific e-mail address, with the list of receivers from the original MailMessage in the topic. The reason for this is, that the client for this project wants to play around with the site in development environment and receive all e-mails with information about who should have received each e-mail.

Comment: @Martin - Well, sounds like you can simply send an _extra_ message with diagnostic info (like the list of intended recipients) to a specifies address. Something that you can use the `ConditionalAttribute` with.

Comment: @Martin: Various ways of doing that. Main suggestion from me to have `SmtpClient` created as a local variable. Then apply what what Oded said in terms of conditional compilation.