# SmtpException occurring in System.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create an asp page that has a form. When the form is submitted, it should send an email out.

ASPX markup

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <p>Please provide your comments</p>
<p>Your name:<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="YourName" runat="server" Width="150px" /><br />
Your email address:<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="YourEmail" runat="server" Width="150px" /><br />
Your comments:<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="Comments" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Width="400px" />
</p>
<p>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</p> 
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
        {
            message.From = new MailAddress(YourEmail.Text.ToString());
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("example@email.com"));
            message.CC.Add(new MailAddress("example2@email.com"));
            message.Subject = "Message via My Site from " + YourName.Text.ToString();
            message.Body = Comments.Text.ToString();
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "127.0.0.1";
            client.Send(message);
        }
    }
```

The error I'm receiving

> An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Inspect the exception. There's a Message or an InnerException that will tell you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: I don't see any exception handling in your posted code. Add a Try Catch before you send and examine the SmtpException. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be running a SMTP server on your local machine and it needs to be listening on 127.0.0.1 for this code to work.

It is more normal to use a different machine for SMTP, or for development purposes install a smtp server, such as those mentioned at [development smtp server for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353439/development-smtp-server-for-windows).

Additionally if you put a try catch arround the code dealing with the smtpclient you would be able to get the exception message and additional information.

Ben

Comment: I guess I didn't have a good enough understanding of how this worked. Thank you for the insight.