# Service which presents your outgoing email as a draft email when testing on localhost?

Tags: php, email

Lots of answers here and elsewhere on Google for how to setup your WAMP or XAMP on localhost to send emails.

However for testing/developing, you mostly don't care about emails actually getting transmitted. You just want to check how they're formed, and whether the email picked up the correct settings and options.

So, I remember having this problem a few months ago and finding a solution/service which did this:

As soon as my PHP code triggered an outgoing email, it would present it as a real draft email in a new window in my email client (Outlook, as it happens). I could check the from/to/subject/body instantly and easily. Nothing actually got transmitted, and I didn't have to keep a bunch of inboxes open somewhere or worry about delays or junk folders.

Trouble is I can't remember how I set this thing up. It was either a service which I downloaded and installed or it was a tutorial on how to set this up in WAMP. It was possibly a WordPress plugin but I'm not sure. I am certain it was free.

Does anyone recognise this kind of setup for email testing in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is a PHP configuration and not a software?

I used a mail smtp 'catcher' that works as you describe.

I hope it could be useful for your interests: Test Mail Server Tool (http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I'm 95% certain that's exactly what I was using! Certainly now that you've named it I find it's installed her on my machine and the icon looks familiar. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool. I am happy to help you!

Answer (score 0):

I'll be accepting Nacho's answer. For completeness ... following StackOverflow's **Related** questions and checking out some other answers, I see there's also a service called [Papercut](http://papercut.codeplex.com/) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072294/180430), which I might also check out.