# Dummy SMTP server for development purposes

Tags: scripting, smtp, batch-file, email

I've been using a dummy smtp server called DevNull SMTP so that I can test my app which sends out notification emails.  It has a nice simple GUI, very helpful, but can't be scripted easily.  I can't even start it listening to port 25.  I have to run the app and then click on the start button...

Is there a similar app that can be scripted easily?  Scripted in the sense that I can control it from a bash script or windows batch file and possibly even query the emails from my unit/functional tests.

Comment: you can take a look at the answers posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550887/testing-smtp-with-net

Comment: check this http://enbiso.github.io/dummy-smtp-server/

Comment: Checkout mailnest.io. It is one of the best email testing solutions available in the market. It also has a free plan to start with.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

there is a nice trick with python: http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2010/10/15/fake-smtp-server-with-python/

Just one liner can do the job (listens on port `2500`):

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:2500
```

Comment: legend - incredibly useful!

Comment: That is the most useful trick I have seen in programming, ever.

Comment: One line. No installation. Job done!

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer** - I work for the company behind this service linked to below.

You can also use a hosted email testing service like [Mailosaur](https://mailosaur.com). Some of them (ours included) come with an API for integrating into your tests.

That way if you hit a problem you've got someone else to do the hard work in adding new features, etc. for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Since I stumbled during my research over this question, here is what I ended up with:

For unit testing you can use [subethasmtp](http://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/). Base on subethasmtp I also wrote a program that you can use to call from scripts an query the results: [developmentSMTP](https://github.com/yankee42/developmentSMTP)